# SQL commad to copy just one column from line to line and to insert it into another from

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have very little SQL knowledge, so I would be happy if someone could help me with the right command.

I have database table called "ps_customer" from where I want to copy column "id_customer" BUT **from ID to ID** and to insert them into table "ps_customer_group" in column name "id_customer" and "id_group" 2 for all inserted line

Comment: I think you will get more answers if you share an example of what you are trying to achieve and what you tried till now

Comment: I have no such knowledge and so far I have not tested anything

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The question is not clear.  You should also tag with the database you are using.